# VBScript unable to write http.ResponseBody to ADODB Stream

Tags: http, vbscript

I am sending an HTTP POST to an API with a json request to download a zip file. The response contains the zip file in the responseBody. I have verified this sequence in Postman with the responsebody containing the zip file.

I am attempting to save the zip file from the http response body to a local file doing the following in VBScript:

```
    Sub Download_Study_Bundle
    URL = myURL
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic base64encodeduserandpassword"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "charset=UTF-8"
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
    json = myjson
    objHTTP.send (json)

    dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
            with bStrm
                .type = 1 '//binary
                .open
                .write objHTTP.responseBody
                .savetofile myFile, 2 '//overwrite
            end with
    end sub
```

I get an error on line : ".write objHTTP.responseBody"

that states:
"Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another."

I can see in my logs that I get a proper 200 response with something in ResponseBody. I am unable to figure out why the responseBody cannot be written as a binary stream to the ADODB object. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: a screenshot of the same json sent in postman produces the raw zip file in the response body:
[http response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf7dC.jpg)

Comment: You're telling the remote server that you accept `application/json`, what is the response meant to be? Is it a raw ZIP file or is it a JSON response containing some encoded data that represents the file? Would remove `accept` header.

Comment: The response is a raw zip file in the response body. What you have said totally makes sense.
I went ahead and commented out the "accept" line and I am still seeing the same error in the same place. Do I need to specify a different "accept" maybe?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, would check what the response contains first using something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: I am able to see the raw response using the same sequence in postman, I have confirmed with the API developer that it is a raw zip file in the response body.

Comment: I understand that but testing in Postman doesn’t necessarily mean it’s "like for like", you need to run something like Fiddler to see what is being returned when you run the VBScript.

Comment: dim bstr as Adodb.stream, and put brackets around (ObjHTTP.responsebody).  vbscript has to guess information for the late binding, and sometimes it does it wrong.  (If that doesn't work, you can test with javascript example: it that doesn't work you have a client-server or method problem, not a vbscript problem)